# Browser Side Photo Editing Library

Tags: javascript, flash, image

Currently I'm searching for a free solution to simple edit some photos at the users browser. Resizing and Cropping would be mandatory.
I'm not searching for an online service (for example [SUMO](http://www.sumopaint.com/home/) or [PIXLR](http://www.pixlr.com/editor/) which are great), because I want to include the software into a WYSIWYG Editor.

JavaScript would be really nice, but it would have to work in IE 8.
[Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/) is a great example, but works only in modern browsers (not IE 8 :-/)

Any suggestions what I could use?

Maybe setting up some kind of image processing service with ImageMagick and communicating with it through AJAX could also be an solution? Has anyone gained some experience with such a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to server side image processing, then you can look at some basic image transformations that Google app engine provides.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html#Transform

Comment: I'm not able to use any Google Services, but I will build this on my own. It will be a simple webservice with image magick.

Answer (score 0):

This might be interesting. though not supporting crop
[Agile uploader](http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html)

Maybe its possible to mingle with [JS image processing lib](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try MarvinJ for Javascript image processing in the browser side. Very easy to use it:

```
// Load image and manipulate color channel
image.load("https://i.imgur.com/ZcCe0eC.jpg", function(){
    image.draw(canvasA);
    Marvin.colorChannel(image, image, 14, 0, -8);
    image.draw(canvasB);
});
```

Basically, it loads the pixel data for an image in the web and provides many algorithms to manipulate it.

Few examples (JSFiddle included):

- [Playing with image processing in Javascript using MarvinJ 1.0](https://www.marvinj.org/en/releases/marvinj_1.0.html)